# RSOCKT Encoder/Decoder using with byte[] pool

Tags: rsocket-java

I have written my own custom Encoder and Decoder to keep the payload size slim. Currently, byte[] is created for every message, I am trying to implement a byte[] pool to reduce the number of objects being created. I am looking for a post-sent event i.e. an event that tells me that the bytes have been written to the socket, so that I can return the byte[] back to the pool. Can someone please help me with the solution?